# Login page error message

Tags: c#

I am using ASP.NET to create a Registration form.As part of my studies i have just created a Login page that include a username field and a password field.Now i would like to know How to display an error message/alert when a user fails to enter his/her username/password???. while clicking the Login button if any of the username or password field is empty, there should be an alert showing error.Thanks ...

here is what i have done yet... What all i have to do to show an alert box???

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
        </td>
        <td class="style4">
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style6">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" class="style2">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username *"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style6">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" class="style2">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password *"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style6">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style2">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click" Width="100px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the error message we can have Label or Literal control or any other as per our requirement. Initially we should set their visibility to false and from server side on button click we can display proper error messages and set visibility to true.

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:label>` through....

check this  [Server Controls Overview of msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306459)

Answer (score 0):

Check
[ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Validation example for Login form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx)